# regex select only the http://www part of the hyperlink

Tags: python, regex

I have searched the forum and couldn't find anything that could solve my question. I am trying to retrieve only the link to a website from a hyperlink, for example.

I have 68 different lines like this:

```
href="/creditrating/Pages/Home.aspx" class="rmLink">
<span class="rmText">Centre for Credit Rating</span></a></li>
<li class="rmItem "><a href="http://www.creative-growth.eu/" class="rmLink">
<span class="rmText">Creative Growth Project</span></a></li><li class="rmItem ">
<a href="/faculties/health-life-social-sciences/centres/Pages/Placements-Practice-Education-Centre.aspx" class="rmLink">
<span class="rmText">Placements &amp; Practice Education Centre</span></a></li>
<li class="rmItem "><a href="/research/centresandprojects/smartcities/Pages/Smart-Cities.aspx" class="rmLink">
<span class="rmText">Smart Cities</span></a></li>
<li class="rmItem rmLast"><a href="/research/centresandprojects/src/Pages/src.aspx" class="rmLink"><span class="rmText">Scottish Resource Centre for Women in SET</span></a>
</li>
```

All I need is the link in this case http://www.creative-growth.eu/

I would like to do this using regular expressions. Could you also give me an explanation of the code?

Comment: Are asking about finding absolute URLs and ignoring relative URLs?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex that captures `href="(http(s?):\/\/[^"]+)"`

This will capture links and also whether or not they reference HTTPS sites

Comment: I was missing a ``+``

Comment: the links may be ftp|www|smb: etc.,

Answer (score 0):

```
http://[^/]+/
```

starts with http:// 
take any character except / 
ends with /

Comment: You don't take into account that he might want a full path, his sample is ambiguous, also he wanted the link, yours will capture any http://

Comment: all true, I took website to be just the domain name, not the full link